# A Poisson point process question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Q) A fair coin is tossed at independent Exp($1$) distributed intervals. Every time a coin is tossed, we win $1\$$ with probability $1/2$ and loose $1\$$ with probability $1/2$. Let $Y_t$ be the number of dollars won at time $t$ ($Y_t$ = negative number means there is a net loss).

1) Find $EY_t$, $Var(Y_t)$

We have a Poisson point process of coin tosses because the interarrivals are exponentially distributed.

$\text{Let } X_t\sim Bin(N,1/2) \text{ where } N\sim Pois(t)$

$\implies Y_t = X_t - (N - X_t) = 2X_t - N$

$\implies EY_t = E[E[Y_t|N]] = E[N - N]=0$

$Var(Y_t) = E[Var(Y_t|N)] + Var(E[Y_t|N]) = E[Var(2X_t-N|N)]+0 = E[4N\times1/2\times 1/2] = EN = t$

> Is the above attempt correct?

2) Find $\log E[e^{uY_t}]$

Using a similar logic,

$$\begin{align}
\log E[e^{uY_t}] &= \log E[E[e^{2uX_t-N}|N]] \\
&= \log E[\frac{1}{e^N}E[e^{2uX_t}|N] \\
&= \log E[\frac{1}{e^N}\sum_{j=0}^N e^{2uj}{N \choose j}(1/2)^N]
\end{align}
$$

> and since this is a random sum, I was thinking Wald's equation but there are several conditions to check and am wondering if there is another way to find $(2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, everything you wrote seems to be correct except that $uY_t=2uX_t-uN$ and not $2uX_t-N$. In order to solve (2), you can use the identity
$$\sum_{j=0}^N e^{2uj}\binom{N}{j}=(1+e^{2u})^N.$$
You then get
\begin{align*}
\log E[e^{uY_t}]&=\log E\left[\frac{1}{e^{uN}}\sum_{j=0}^N e^{2uj}{N \choose j}(1/2)^N\right]\\
&=\log E\left[((1+e^{2u})/2e^u)^N\right]\\
&=\log\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{((1+e^{2u})/2e^u)^k t^k e^{-t}}{k!}\right)\\
&=t\left(\frac{1+e^{2u}}{2e^u}-1\right).
\end{align*}